# pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "mydb" failed: FATAL: database "mydb" does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku, command-line, pg-dump

ok, following [these instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import) I've runned:

```
$ PGPASSWORD=mypassword pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser mydb > mydb.dump
```

in the same folder where the database is (app_db.sql) but I keep getting:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "mydb" failed: FATAL:  database "mydb" does not exist
```

Why is this happening and what can I do solve it?

Thanks

Comment: What's unclear about "*database "mydb" does not exist*"?

Comment: It's unclear the fact that the database does exists, and it's in the same folder, so I want to know why it says the database doesn't exists

Comment: Then post the output of the `\l` command in `psql`

Comment: The output of \l? what's that?

Comment: It's a command in `psql`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have critically misunderstood how PostgreSQL works.

`app_db.sql` is not a database, it is a *database dump*. A sequence of text commands that describe the data in the database that can be replayed to create the database.

It isn't like a Microsoft Access `.dbx` file or a SQLite3 database file, a database stored in a single file that can be manipulated directly. The only way to work with a PostgreSQL database is via a client/server connection to the PostgreSQL server, which stores the actual database contents in a system dependent location like `/var/lib/pgsql` which you never need to manipulate directly.

To use the database dump, you must *restore it* into a *new empty database* using the `psql` command, eg:

```
$ createdb mydb
$ psql -f app_db.sql mydb
```

This will probably fail with permissions errors if you try to run it exactly as written above. You will need to create yourself a user, give that user ownership of `mydb`, and possibly edit `pg_hba.conf` to allow yourself to authenticate depending on your system settings.

A more realistic example for a user with unix login name `bob` might be:

```
$ sudo -u postgres createuser bob
$ sudo -u postgres createdb -O bob mydb
$ psql -f dpp_db.sql -1 -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 mydb
```

I strongly recommend that you read the [PostgreSQL tutorial](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial.html) and the user manual.